# Boot ISO file via GRUB2

Tags: grub2, live-usb, usb-drive

I'm migrating my multiboot USB drive from syslinux+grub to grub2. I'm now searching a way to boot my ISO files. I'm searching for a chainload method. So I don't want to add kernel and initrd parameters.

This is, how it looks like in grubs menu.lst:

```
title MiniTool Partition Wizard 9
find --set-root /multiboot/ISOS/pwfree9.iso
map /multiboot/ISOS/pwfree9.iso (hd32)
map --hook
root (hd32)
chainloader (hd32)
```

How would this look like in grub.cfg?

Answer (score 1):

To create a `Grub2 menuentry` you must add it to the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file.

Add the menuentry below the existing lines in the file.

Open the /etc/grub.d/40_custom file as root with a text editor.

```
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

Add the menuentry.

Save the file.

Update the Grub 2 menu.

```
sudo update-grub
```

SystemRescuecd example:

```
menuentry '[loopback]systemrescuecd-x86-4.5.2' {
    set isofile='/boot/iso/systemrescuecd-x86-4.5.2.iso'
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/isolinux/rescue64 isoloop=$isofile
    initrd (loop)/isolinux/initram.igz
}
```

Ubuntu example:

```
menuentry '[loopback]ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64' {
    set isofile='/boot/iso/ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso'
    loopback loop $isofile
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile locale=en_US.UTF-8
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/)

Comment: I know how to do that. What I'm looking for is a method to chainload. I don't want to specify any paths inside the ISO. Take a look add my example. It's universally usable for other ISOs and I get the boot menu or what ever of the ISO. Could it be GRUB2 isn't able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **grub4dos** and the partnew command but I don't think grub2 is capable of doing the same thing though.
The partnew command writes a partition entry to the USB drive (e.g. ptn #4) and then you can boot 99% of all linux ISOs directly with no special menu - the same menu will work for pretty much all linux ISOs.
http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/tails
http://www.easy2boot.com/faq-/how-e2b-works/

Comment: My sample code is from grub4dos. It's not what I'm looking for but it's interesting.